# How can I add text to SQL Column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to update 1 column in SQL Table. Example: Current value in column is like this

```
2013/09/pizzalover.jpg 
2013/10/pasta.jpg
```

Now i want to update whole column like this : www.mypizza.com/2013/09/pizzalover.jpg 
Is there any way I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: update <yourtable> set <yourcolumn> = 'www.mypizza.com/' + <yourcolumn>?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: this worked great for me update oc_product set sku= CONCAT('BBC', sku); but how can I make it so it only adds to the column when there is no occurrence of the text BBC in the column for any that are added after the initial SQL run. as every day new ones are added on auto and I can't change the way they are added. thanks in advance from anyone who can help. so this my best option to add to the sku of every product.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply update column using statement

```
update TableName set ColumnName  = 'www.mypizza.com/' + ColumnName
```

Comment: Be careful of using "+" your db instance might interpret the following string as a number and truncate the whole thing. Use concat instead if your db supports it

Answer (score 13):

If you are using MYSql, you can use the [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) as :

```
update tableName set columnName= CONCAT('www.mypizza.com/', columnName);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dd15/1)

If you are using oracle you can use the [concatenation operator '||'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) as :

```
update tableName set "columnName"='www.mypizza.com/'||"columnName";
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c6549/1)

In SQL Server you can use [`+` for string concatenation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) as:

```
update tableName set name='www.mypizza.com/'+columnName;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3aa68/1)

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?:

```
SELECT 'www.mypizza.com/' + ColumnName AS ColumnName FROM TableName
```

Depending on the rest of your application environment, there is likely a *much* better way to accomplish this.  But in terms of just using SQL to add static text to a column in a SELECT statement, you can just concatenate the text directly in the statement.

Or, if you wanted to *UPDATE* the column values, something like this:

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = 'www.mypizza.com/' + ColumnName
```

Same principle, just using an `UPDATE` instead of a `SELECT`, which will modify the underlying data instead of just modifying the view of the data.

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. The concatenation operator in standard SQL is `||` not `+` (`+` is for adding numbers)

Answer (score 2):

OP doesn't specify which DBMS they are using. The following is for Postgres to update a text column by adding a prefix to it (tested with PostgreSQL v11):

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET column_1  = 'start_text_' || column_1
WHERE column_1 LIKE 'prefix_%'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the information stored in your database and then edit it, you can do that like this:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `blog-posts`  WHERE `id` = 11";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$post = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$title = $post['title'];
$title .= "aapje";
echo $title
?>
```

And then update your database like normal:

```
$updateq = "UPDATE `blog-posts`  SET `title` = '$title' WHERE `id` = 11";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQlite3, you may`||` oparator.

For Ex:

```
update Diodes set KICAD_SCHLIB = "ORELTEK_lib:" || "Library Ref" where "Library Ref" not in  ("Resistor" ,"Capacitor", "ELEC_Capacitor", "Inductance", "Feridbeed", "STD_Diode", "Schottky_Diode", "LED", "TVS_Diode", "Zener_Diode")
```